# Rexx - Parse a CSV line (';' separator)

Tags: parsing, csv, rexx

I know that we can parse a CSV line ( ';' separator ) with something like that :

```
delim = ';'
myline="i;want;to;know;what;love;is"
parse var myline w1 (delim) w2 (delim) w3 (delim) w4 (delim) w5 (delim) w6 (delim) w7
say w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 w6 w7
```

I want to know if there is a way to simplify the iteration of the 'w# (delim)'in order to do something like :

```
parse var myline w1 (delim) w2 (delim) ... (delim) w6 (delim) w7
/* then we will have all w1 to w7 defined
```

I could do a function with some array to do that but is it possible natively on rexx, i was just wondering

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure, if what you really want is `n` variables named `w1`, `w2`, ... `wn`:

```
do i = 1 by 1 while myline <> ''
    parse var myline word (delim) myline
    interpret "w" || i "= word"
end
```

But the Rexx-y way to do this is using a "stem array":

```
delim = ';'
do i = 1 by 1 while myline <> ''
    parse var myline w.i (delim) myline
end
w.0 = i-1
```

or even:

```
do i = 1 by 1 while myline <> ''
    parse var myline w.i ';' myline
end
w.0 = i-1
```

When you're done, you have an array `w.` with it's count in `w.0` and the `n` words in `w.1`, `w.2`, ... up through `w.n`.  This is better because Rexx has special handling for the part following the `.`: you can use any variable, and its value will be used instead.  So printing all those words is just:

```
do i = 1 to w.0
    say w.i
end
```

Or re-assembling them is just:

```
line = ""
do i = 1 to w.0
    line = line || w.i || ';'
end
```

Comment: I didn't know that Parse was assigning the remaining words. Thanks, tha help me a lot.

Comment: I think you need a terminating condition for the DO loop. Try appending a delimiter to the end of `MYLINE` then `DO I = 1 BY 1 UNTIL STRIP(MYLINE) = ''`

Comment: @NealB Yeah, that'll teach me to type code without running it.  Updated with `while myline <> ''`, that'll do the job.

Comment: the `do i = 1 by 1 while myline <> ''` is perfect as a loop (@NealB). The assign `w.0 = i` is wrong in my Rexx: `i` is incremented before the until is tested: so it would be `w.0 = i - 1`

Comment: @Martin Yeah, I typed that code, I didn't run it.  Fixed now.

Comment: Many is the time I've wished Rexx allowed expressions as stem suffixes.  Then I'd do something like:

`do w.0 = 1 by 1 while myline <> ''
    parse var myline w.(w.0) ';' myline
end`